# Mac10.14, 10.14 vm's xcode unable to launch simulator on azure hosted agents for reactnative builds

Tags: ios, xcode, azure

We are trying to automate our build process as well Testing process. During our build Process we encountered a problem Azure hosted mac vm's unable to start simulator's

Application:Reactnative -IOS

xcode:10

node:12.X

mac 10.4,10.3

```
   Error:

   Scanning folders for symlinks in /Users/vsts/agent/2.155.1/work/1/s/node_modules (21ms)
   Found Xcode workspace SchemaXXX.xcworkspace
   Could not find iPhone 6 simulator 
   For Testing we are using detox automation. It is working fine other 3rd party mac vms.

  Error:In Azure Devops says device not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

The feedback applies to another product: detox. We recommend that you submit the feedback to that product team at [stackoverflowDetox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/detox.) .

Well one of the fix can be seen here [gitHub](https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/1675)